# Hydraulic cylinders

Tags: control-engineering, hydraulics

As part of my final year project, I am designing a racehorse simulator. I want to use 2 hydraulic actuators - one at the front and one at the back to simulate jumping.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what I need to make this happen and how to control it? I have no experience using hydraulics. The shaded area under the simulator is where I intend to attach them.

[image]

Comment: I highly encourage you to rely on a design which does not put the user of the device anywhere in line with the hydraulic/pneumatic cylinders. I have seen too many people die or get severely injured by not expecting a cylinder come apart. Unfortunately metal fatigue in cylinder walls and pistons are not often thought of (including in newly manufactured/remanufactured) parts.

Answer (score 3):

Hydraulic (or pneumatic) cylinders are merely a means to provide a linear force between two points. You select the cylinder based on how much force, how much distance and how much speed you need for the relative motion of those two points.

It is up to you, the designer, to constrain that force through additional mechanical linkages in order to get the specific motion you desire. For example, if you study a typical backhoe digger, you'll see that each cylinder forms one side of a triangle. The other sides are rigid links that control how the changing length of the cylinder produces the desired motion.

[image: photo of backhoe]

The first step for your simulator is to figure out exactly what movements you want to produce, including a consideration of the accelerations you intend to use, then design the linkages that will allow those movements while not allowing unwanted movements. Only then can you consider how to power those movements with cylinders.

As your question stands, this is a very broad topic — probably too broad for StackExchange's Q and A format.

Comment: The weight of the artefact will be 200kg (ball part figure) and i am looking for a rise of about 500mm/second. I see what you mean about using the linkages to get the desired movements. Thanks very much this will help me no end

Answer (score 1):

Hydraulics normally run very high pressures and produce very large forces and are normally limited to heavy industries; use pneumatics instead if you want a fluid solution. At the minimum, air cylinder, values, fittings, and airline tubing is needed. If a solenoid instead of manually controlled valve is used, a control system such as programmable logic controller is needed.

Comment: Thanks The weight of the artefact will be 200kg (ball part figure) and i am looking for a rise of about 500mm/second. But this is something i will take into consideration